# Removing Last Updated value when No data was selected from the column to check

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I need help with my Google Sheet script. It is working fine when showing the timestamp of "Last Updated" at col B every time a new Call Status was set at col A; but when I delete the status at col A, the timestamp remains at col B. It should also be cleared when no data is selected at col A.

[Link to my Google Sheet](https://t.ly/z2P0)

**My Script**

```
    var timezone = "UTC+00:00";
    var timestamp_format = "hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy"; // Timestamp Format.
    var updateColName = "Call Status";
    var timeStampColName = "Last Updated";

    var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('StatusDate'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.
    var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
    var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
    var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
    var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
    
    if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
        var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
        var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
        cell.setValue(date);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The script is not complete and there are missing details like if this is a simple or a installable trigger, a description of what you tried and / or where did you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation:

- You can simply check whether the new value in column `A` is blank.
- If it is blank, then set the value in column `B` also to blank, otherwise, set `date`.
- You can use a [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to achieve your
  goal in one line of code.

Replace the last line:

```
cell.setValue(date);
```

with:

```
e.value == '' ? cell.setValue('') : cell.setValue(date);
```

### Solution:

```
var timezone = "UTC+00:00";
var timestamp_format = "hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy";  // Timestamp Format
var updateColName = "Call Status";
var timeStampColName = "Last Updated";

var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('StatusDate');  //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script
var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;

if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { 
  var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
  e.value == '' ? cell.setValue('') : cell.setValue(date); // new code
}
```